# Jquery bxslider exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

Alright so the problem is basically unknown for me, never had it before.
I tried adding bxslider today but it seems it doesnt work properly. I tried using the other version of the JS that he provided but same thing happends, the images keep on "loading" and they never load. I did inspect element and this is what I got

> jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
>       at jQuery.fn.load (file:///C:/Users/Oploditelj/Desktop/domaci_last/js/jquery-3.0.0.js:9612:12)
>       at HTMLImageElement. (file:///C:/Users/Oploditelj/Desktop/domaci_last/js/plugin/jquery.bxslider.min.js:10:4394)
>       at Function.each (file:///C:/Users/Oploditelj/Desktop/domaci_last/js/jquery-3.0.0.js:359:19)
>       at jQuery.each (file:///C:/Users/Oploditelj/Desktop/domaci_last/js/jquery-3.0.0.js:152:17)
>       at HTMLImageElement. (file:///C:/Users/Oploditelj/Desktop/domaci_last/js/plugin/jquery.bxslider.min.js:10:4355)
>       at Function.each (file:///C:/Users/Oploditelj/Desktop/domaci_last/js/jquery-3.0.0.js:359:19)
>       at jQuery.each (file:///C:/Users/Oploditelj/Desktop/domaci_last/js/jquery-3.0.0.js:152:17)
>       at g (file:///C:/Users/Oploditelj/Desktop/domaci_last/js/plugin/jquery.bxslider.min.js:10:4295)
>       at c (file:///C:/Users/Oploditelj/Desktop/domaci_last/js/plugin/jquery.bxslider.min.js:10:4180)
>       at d (file:///C:/Users/Oploditelj/Desktop/domaci_last/js/plugin/jquery.bxslider.min.js:10:2570)
>   undefined

The code that Im using is exactly the same as the one that was on their website.

```
<head> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>

        <script src="js/plugin/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/plugin/jquery.bxslider.css"/>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/skripta.js"></script>


    </head> <!-- Head ends -->
```

and of course Im calling it inside separate .js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.bxslider').bxSlider();

});
```

and the body is

```
<body> <!-- Body start -->
        <ul class="bxslider">
          <li><img src="js/plugin/images/pic1.jpg"/></li>
          <li><img src="js/plugin/images/pic2.jpg"/></li>
          <li><img src="js/plugin/images/pic3.jpg"/></li>
        </ul>

    </body><!-- Body ends -->
```

Comment: Also when I add any code after $('.bxslider').bxSlider() it wont be called. Its like its not being loaded at all

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The issue is about jQuery version 3.0 and compatibility with `bxslider.js`. And this issue was arised by jQuery `.load()` function. You have to change `bxslider.js`'s one line to solve this issue. Open your bxslider.js file and find `.load()` function's code line. It was used only 1 time in `bxslider.js`, so the necessary change is:

From

```
$(this).load();
```

To

```
$(this).trigger('load');
```

Comment: You are a saviour @kkakkurt! Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome @Manik Arora, I'm glad to help you :)

Comment: @kkakkurt I can't find it in my js file.

Comment: A general update for anyone coming into this question now-ish(Late 2017), if you update to the newest version of bxSlider, it fixes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There's a pull request on github that solves this:

https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/pull/1024

I'd recommend you test it out.

Comment: https://github.com/Rahisify/bxslider-4 also has this built in - still has some functional quirks with jquery 3.1.1 though... but at least it is being maintained a bit.