# bxslider directive throwing error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, bxslider

I am using angularjs in my application where I have created a directive for bxslider. Below is code of directive:

```
angular.module('sbAdminApp')
.directive('bxSlider', function(){
    return{
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
            element.ready(function(){
                $($(element[0])).bxSlider({
                    maxSlides:1,
                    auto:true,
                    controls:false,
                    pager:true
                });
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Above I am using like this `$($(element[0])).bxSlider({` after ready function as I **search for a problem where bxslider should work with ng-repeat** and found this solution after which bxslider is working but sometimes images doesn't load and I can see this error always.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Finally i got the answer after so many searches

This is not a angularjs error this is a jquery version compatibility with bxslider.

Issue is arised by jQuery `.load()` function.

In bxslider.js file find `.load()` function's code line. It was used only 1 time in bxslider.js.

From

```
$(this).load();
```

To

```
$(this).trigger('load');
```

Thanks to kkakkurt for this great solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/38562965/4119808

Comment: Thanks for this! Looks like I'm going to need to use the bootstrap compatible version of this slider if I don't want to have to deal with custom bxslider files.

https://github.com/Rahisify/bxslider-4

Comment: `$(window).on('load',myFunction());` gives the same error. What can we do then?

Comment: u need to show me the instance where this error appers

Comment: Thanks @GauravAggarwal, this was the solution after so many searches!