# Image Slider does not work at random moments

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have created an Image Slider using jQuery, but it doesn't work at random moments. After reloading the page I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
at i.fn.init.i.fn.load (jquery?v=eJAcMfrInnLuvmR6YmGFt2ky0cO2ssn2OaxtB6iWFKQ1:1)
at HTMLImageElement.<anonymous> (slider?v=iXGFgGvKoKTyJMnF1faQOZMvYM6od0eK7irNUQ3FiMg1:1)
at Function.each (jquery?v=eJAcMfrInnLuvmR6YmGFt2ky0cO2ssn2OaxtB6iWFKQ1:1)
at i.fn.init.each (jquery?v=eJAcMfrInnLuvmR6YmGFt2ky0cO2ssn2OaxtB6iWFKQ1:1)
at HTMLImageElement.<anonymous> (slider?v=iXGFgGvKoKTyJMnF1faQOZMvYM6od0eK7irNUQ3FiMg1:1)
at Function.each (jquery?v=eJAcMfrInnLuvmR6YmGFt2ky0cO2ssn2OaxtB6iWFKQ1:1)
at i.fn.init.each (jquery?v=eJAcMfrInnLuvmR6YmGFt2ky0cO2ssn2OaxtB6iWFKQ1:1)
at et (slider?v=iXGFgGvKoKTyJMnF1faQOZMvYM6od0eK7irNUQ3FiMg1:1)
at ft (slider?v=iXGFgGvKoKTyJMnF1faQOZMvYM6od0eK7irNUQ3FiMg1:1)
at k (slider?v=iXGFgGvKoKTyJMnF1faQOZMvYM6od0eK7irNUQ3FiMg1:1)
```

Controller:

```
 public class SliderController : Controller
{
    // GET: Slider
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (BasDbContext db = new BasDbContext())
        {
            return View(db.gallery.ToList());
        }
        //return View();
    }

    //Add Images in slider

    public ActionResult AddImage()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddImage(HttpPostedFileBase ImagePath)
    {
        if (ImagePath != null)
        {
            // You can skip this block, because it is only to force the user to upload specific resolution pics
            //System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ImagePath.InputStream);
            //if ((img.Width != 800) || (img.Height != 356))
            //{
            //    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Image resolution must be 800 x 356 pixels");
            //    return View();
            //}

            // Upload your pic
            string pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ImagePath.FileName);

            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@"\cdm\Content\images\"), pic);
            ImagePath.SaveAs(path);
            using (BasDbContext db = new BasDbContext())
            {
                Gallery gallery = new Gallery { ImagePath = @"\cdm\Content\images\" + pic };
                db.gallery.Add(gallery);
                db.gallery.Add(gallery).DateAdded = gallery.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    // Delete Multiple Images
    public ActionResult DeleteImages()
    {
        using (BasDbContext db = new BasDbContext())
        {
            return View(db.gallery.ToList());
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteImages(IEnumerable<int> ImagesIDs)
    {
        using (BasDbContext db = new BasDbContext())
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var id in ImagesIDs)
                {
                    var image = db.gallery.Single(s => s.ID == id);
                    string imgPath = Server.MapPath(image.ImagePath);
                    db.gallery.Remove(image);
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(imgPath))
                        System.IO.File.Delete(imgPath);
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch
            {
                TempData["AlertMessage"] = "Something went wrong, try again";
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("DeleteImages");
    }
}
```

}

Index:

```
@model IEnumerable<ConcremoteDeviceManagment.Models.Gallery>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    //Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}
@if (TempData["AlertMessage"] != null)
{
    <p class="alert alert-danger" id="successMessage">@TempData["AlertMessage"]</p>
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<p>
    <button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AddImage", "Slider")';return false; " class="btn btn-primary">Add Image</button>
    <button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("DeleteImages", "Slider")';return false; " class="btn btn-danger">Delete Image</button>
</p>
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/SliderPartial.cshtml", Model)
```

SliderPartial:

```
 <div class="bxslider">
        @foreach (var image in Model)
        {
            <div><img src="@Url.Content(image.ImagePath)" /></div>
        }
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            mode: 'fade',
            captions: true,
            slideWidth: 600
        });
    });
</script>
```

I think something is going wrong in SliderPartial.
Controller and Index seems to be fine.

I hope somebody is able to help me out.
More information will be given when needed

Comment: Could you post your code. That will help

Comment: I think the variable that you are sending in `indexOf` is null

Comment: Definitely going to need some code posted here. Like Lavahound said, it is almost definitely going to be a null variable in `indexOf` but without the code we can't know which one.

Comment: @Lavahound code is added

Comment: `.bxSlider` has to be written in the following format: https://bxslider.com/examples/image-slideshow-captions/

Comment: @Lavahound Still getting the same error

Comment: Can you post your updated `Slider Partial` code?

Comment: @Lavahound Js code is updated. still works at random moments

Comment: Try removing the `foreach` loop and post the images the same way they have been mentioned in the link

Comment: <div class="bxslider">
  <div><img src="/assets/images/coffee1.jpg" title="Funky roots"></div>
  <div><img src="/assets/images/coffee2.jpg" title="The long and winding road"></div>
  <div><img src="/assets/images/coffee3.jpg" title="Happy trees"></div>
</div>

Comment: <div><img src="/assets/images/coffee1.jpg" title="Funky roots"></div>

Comment: Specify them in this format

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168125/discussion-between-lavahound-and-rol-dfa).

Comment: @Lavahound thank for trying, I still don't know what is causing the error. I think the best solution is to develop a new way to Delete/upload and view system

Comment: related, if not a dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38911759/bxslider-directive-throwing-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-ind  Are you using an old version of that bxslider because the issue described in the dupe seems fixed here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/master/src/js/jquery.bxslider.js and with that version I can't repro your issue.

Comment: @rene I am using version 4.2.12, still getting the same error. Is it a possibilty something going wrong with including the file?

Comment: I have no idea as you don't show what your page DOM looks like when the error happens. Which version jQuery do you use? Is there any other javascript hooked up? Maybe twice? Replace your minified version with the full blown bxslider.js (and/or disable the bundler) so you can at least see normal names in the callstack when the error occurs.